# how to translate "low self-esteem" to German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I gave it several tries, but I am really not sure, whether or not anything is correct.

> schlechtes Selbstwertsgefühl
>   niedriges Selbstwertsgefühl

Thank you in advance.

This is what I think might be a good German translation of the English sentence I have in mind:

> Er ist ein talentierter und intelligenter Mann, aber wegen seines schlechten Selbstwertgefühls hatte er sich nicht um diese Stelle beworben.

Comment: It's not »Selbstwert-**s**-gefühl« but just »Selbstwertgefühl« without Fugen-S. To choose the right attribute we need more context. Both versions are possible, but it depends on the context. Give us an example of a complete sentence or describe the situation where you want to use this expression.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, 

Er ist ein talentierter und intelligenter Mann, aber, weigen seines schlechtes Selbstwertgefühl, hatte er sich nicht um diese Stelle beworben.

Comment: It would have been better if you edited your question yourself, but now I did it for you. You still can edit it if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better version of your sentence is this:

> Er ist ein talentierter und intelligenter Mann, aber wegen seines **mangelnden Selbstvertrauens** hatte er sich nicht um diese Stelle beworben.

So, in this case it is one of those:

> mangelndes Selbstvertrauen
>   schwach ausgeprägtes Selbstvertrauen
>   geringes Selbstvertrauen

The noun should be »Selbstvertrauen«, not »Selbstwertgefühl«. Later means something that doesn't fit very well into this sentence:

### Selbstwertgefühl

This literally is: self-value-feeling. It is what you think of yourself how valuable you are. If you think that the value that you represent is high (i.e. if you think you are a valuable person), than you have a high *Selbstwertgefühl*. If you think you are worthless, you have a low *Selbstwertgefühl.*

### Selbstvertrauen

This is literally: self-trusting. This is how much you trust in you own capabilities. If you think that you can do well whatever you should do, then you have a high *Selbstvertrauen*. If you think you will fail before you even tried, then your *Selbstvertrauen* is low. This often correlates with *Selbstwertgefühl*, but is different from it.

There is another word that is similar to those:

### Selbstachtung

This is literally: self-respect. This is how much respect you have of your own person. This is very close related to *Selbstwertgefühl*, but not exactly the same.

---

now for the attribute:

Your *Selbstvertrauen* can be high or low. This is possible. But it is better to say you have little or much of it. It also can be absent. In German this is:

> Georg hat viel Selbstvertrauen. Er traut sich viel zu.
>   Georg has a lot of self-confidence. He dares a lot.

(I know, my English translations are not always the best. I'm a German native speaker and just try to give you a hint to understand the German sentences)

> Walter ist ängstlich und zaghaft. Er hat kein Selbstvertrauen.
>   Walter is frightened and timid. He has no self-confidence.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are allright (although it's "Selbstwertgefühl" without a connecting "s"). And I'd probably replace "niedrig" or "schlecht" with *schwach* or *mangelnd*.

The standard translation for "low self-esteem" is, however

> mangelndes Selbstbewußtsein

or

> mangelndes Selbstvertrauen

in my opinion.

A possible alternative is also

> mangelnde Selbstachtung

Without any context, however, Hubert is right to say it is impossible to determine what fits best.